# Error in Trac Setup

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to setup a trac, I entered the following lines

```
<Location /trac/[[:alnum]]+/login">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /trac>
  SetHandler mod_python
  PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
  PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
  PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /var/www/trac
  PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
</Location>
```

in this file,

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

but when I'm trying to restart the apache server, I'm getting the following error:

```
Syntax error on line 50 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Invalid command 'PythonInterpreter', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to install libapache2-mod-python first?

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
```

Comment: Already installed

Comment: sudo a2enmod python-this was my problem :)